Why cant I get Snapchat working?
I have it working under Windows 10, so my login details are correct. But on Android, it gives me

Due to repeated failed attempts or other unusual activity, your access to Snapchat has been temporarily disabled.

At this very instant, I can still log on and access Snapchat on Windows.
Using-

Samsung Note 20
With latest updates
On Parallel Space

How can I fix this?

After trying various things, it appears that Snapchat is not happy about Parallel Space.  It runs fine outside of it.
Inside it gives the bogus error in the question.
